# Windows azure CDN blob transactions bill

Tags: azure, transactions, blob, cdn

If I have an icon, 'icon.png' that will be served from the CDN. It is 1K and cached for long time. 1M users hit it from every location in the world.

Q1: because the request is cached 304 on client side will Azure bill me for request when the CLIENT visit my second page and same icon.png served from the cache?

in the bill I will have 1M transactions
OR 1M transactions MULTIPLY by Page view?

Please share average price what you pay for
10000 daily users let say 10 page views per user

I need to understand eTags how are working cached content is it billed on other page

well there are many articles, but this even OLD are not bad
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/07/09/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity.aspx

http://wely-lau.net/2011/12/02/unveiling-the-unforeseen-cost-of-windows-azure-storage-transaction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your first question, you will be billed for the second request for the image, but the cost will be minimal (from [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2011/04/11/understanding-windows-azure-cdn-billing/)):

> Any HTTP(S) request that terminates at the CDN is a billable event.
>   This includes all response types, success, failure, or other. However,
>   different responses may generate very different traffic amounts. For
>   example, 304 NOT MODIFIED (and other header-only) responses generate
>   very little transfer since they are a small header response;
>   similarly, error responses (e.g., 404 NOT FOUND) are billable but
>   incur very little cost because of the tiny response payload.

Your average price and bandwidth will vary based on the amount of data being transferred from your site plus the number of images, CSS, etc. served up from the CDN.

The [Azure pricing calculator](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) and the [CDN pricing page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/) should be a good start for estimating costs.

Comment: RE: "the client has it cached and therefore won't need to call your Azure CDN to retrieve the resource."     I am planing to have Static web site. But I understand the bandwidth bill, I am not clear about Transactions for cached img, js, css  requests did they get transaction when HOSTING STATIC WEB SITE there is request to the server and server respond NOT MODIFIED

Comment: Updated my response with details about the 304 requests. There will be a minimal bandwidth hit since it sends back a header response.